# MySQL Query Not Returning Proper

Tags: mysql, sql, select, where-clause

I'm having a problem with making my MySQL Query below work properly

```
SELECT *
FROM approved_user_info
WHERE user_ID = 101
  AND emailAddress = 'smith546'
  AND SecurityQuestionResponse1 = 'Grapes'
  AND SecurityQuestionResponse2 = 'Office'
  AND SecurityQuestionResponse3 = 'Gardening';
```

For reference, I already inserted a record with the inputted values into the approved_user_info table, but it just shows me an empty table when I highlight the entire query.

For some reason, whenever I highlight this part of the code

```
SELECT *
FROM approved_user_info
WHERE user_ID = 101
```

it works, but not when I highlight the entire query.

I've been trying to find similar questions for an hour but I can't seem to find the right answer (is there is one; perhaps my searching skills suck tbh)

I'd truly appreciate any help and advice

EDIT: Here is my sample data. I apologize for not providing it earlier

[image: My data]

[image: The query I'm executing (it is the first half]

[image: The tables I'm using]

EDIT: Just realized I made a simple mistake of not putting the email address correctly. I apologize for that :')

Comment: You have email without domain in 'emailAddress' field?

Comment: Hi, please add example your database

Comment: The code will work if all the conditions are met in data. Remove conditions 1 by 1 from the first and see when nothing is returned nothing. Also you maybe need and OR or 2 in there rather than all ands. Please publish sample data by selecting without any conditions.

Comment: i guess User_ids are always Unique , so if you query * with a specific User_id, you will get all data from the database corresponding to this ID. This is why it works without the rest

Comment: @RonnySulistio I edited my answer with the related data. I apologize for not uploading it earlier.

Comment: @P.Salmon I edited my answer with the related data. I apologize for not providing it earlier. Likewise, I did check if they matched (and they do thankfully), but it's not working as intended. Personally, I would rather go with the solution I found earlier, but I need to include and match all these other values for an assignment.

Comment: @VitaliyKondratev OMG I just realized :')) It was simple mistake I didn't even notice. Thanks! Lemme go fix and check it rn